# svg stretching to fill the width, adds margin instead

Tags: html, css, svg, frontend

So basically, im trying to make a wave transition between background colours and I put in this svg and it works fine but when I resize to big/full screen screens (desktop) the svg element doesn't stretch to the full width possible [image: image here], my code:

```html
<div class="waves" style="height: 244px;width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" style="display:block;height:100%;">
    <path fill="#36393D" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L18.5,202.7C36.9,213,74,235,111,202.7C147.7,171,185,85,222,74.7C258.5,64,295,128,332,176C369.2,224,406,256,443,234.7C480,213,517,139,554,128C590.8,117,628,171,665,181.3C701.5,192,738,160,775,128C812.3,96,849,64,886,85.3C923.1,107,960,181,997,186.7C1033.8,192,1071,128,1108,85.3C1144.6,43,1182,21,1218,64C1255.4,107,1292,213,1329,250.7C1366.2,288,1403,256,1422,240L1440,224L1440,320L1421.5,320C1403.1,320,1366,320,1329,320C1292.3,320,1255,320,1218,320C1181.5,320,1145,320,1108,320C1070.8,320,1034,320,997,320C960,320,923,320,886,320C849.2,320,812,320,775,320C738.5,320,702,320,665,320C627.7,320,591,320,554,320C516.9,320,480,320,443,320C406.2,320,369,320,332,320C295.4,320,258,320,222,320C184.6,320,148,320,111,320C73.8,320,37,320,18,320L0,320Z"
style="height:100%;width:100%;display:block;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If I set the width to 100% on the svg element it just centers the path image

Answer (score 1):

How about this. I've

1. Added a width:100% to the SVG element's stle.
2. Added preserveAspectRatio="none" so the SVG adapts to the viewport.

```html
<div class="waves" style="height: 244px;width: 100%;overflow-x: hidden;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%;">
    <path fill="#36393D" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L18.5,202.7C36.9,213,74,235,111,202.7C147.7,171,185,85,222,74.7C258.5,64,295,128,332,176C369.2,224,406,256,443,234.7C480,213,517,139,554,128C590.8,117,628,171,665,181.3C701.5,192,738,160,775,128C812.3,96,849,64,886,85.3C923.1,107,960,181,997,186.7C1033.8,192,1071,128,1108,85.3C1144.6,43,1182,21,1218,64C1255.4,107,1292,213,1329,250.7C1366.2,288,1403,256,1422,240L1440,224L1440,320L1421.5,320C1403.1,320,1366,320,1329,320C1292.3,320,1255,320,1218,320C1181.5,320,1145,320,1108,320C1070.8,320,1034,320,997,320C960,320,923,320,886,320C849.2,320,812,320,775,320C738.5,320,702,320,665,320C627.7,320,591,320,554,320C516.9,320,480,320,443,320C406.2,320,369,320,332,320C295.4,320,258,320,222,320C184.6,320,148,320,111,320C73.8,320,37,320,18,320L0,320Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```html
<div class="waves" style="height: 244px;overflow: hidden">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="#36393D" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L18.5,202.7C36.9,213,74,235,111,202.7C147.7,171,185,85,222,74.7C258.5,64,295,128,332,176C369.2,224,406,256,443,234.7C480,213,517,139,554,128C590.8,117,628,171,665,181.3C701.5,192,738,160,775,128C812.3,96,849,64,886,85.3C923.1,107,960,181,997,186.7C1033.8,192,1071,128,1108,85.3C1144.6,43,1182,21,1218,64C1255.4,107,1292,213,1329,250.7C1366.2,288,1403,256,1422,240L1440,224L1440,320L1421.5,320C1403.1,320,1366,320,1329,320C1292.3,320,1255,320,1218,320C1181.5,320,1145,320,1108,320C1070.8,320,1034,320,997,320C960,320,923,320,886,320C849.2,320,812,320,775,320C738.5,320,702,320,665,320C627.7,320,591,320,554,320C516.9,320,480,320,443,320C406.2,320,369,320,332,320C295.4,320,258,320,222,320C184.6,320,148,320,111,320C73.8,320,37,320,18,320L0,320Z"
></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but its not, this causes the waves to get smaller in order to fill the screen, making a gap in between the waves div "half is empty and half is the svg)"